# Strange issue with MySql 5.6 replication

Tags: mysql

I have a strange issue with **MySql 5.6** Master-Master replication. I'm not sure if its entirely a replication issue or a client issue. We have two MySql databases on two different RHEL servers. We have setup a common schema for them and enabled schema level replication. The replication works fine when issuing any DML using the command line utilities or **NaviCat** client on either Master. But it does not seem to replicate the data when using SQL Developer or **MySql WorkBench** clients.

Here is the server information:

```
Linux "Hostname" 2.6.32-431.3.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Dec 13 06:58:20 EST 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Here is the my.cnf file

```
[client]
#password       = your_password
port=3306
socket=./mysql.sock

# Here follows entries for some specific programs

# The MySQL server
[mysqld]
port=3306
socket=./mysql.sock
#skip-locking
key_buffer_size = 16M
max_allowed_packet = 1M
table_open_cache = 64
sort_buffer_size = 512K
net_buffer_length = 8K
read_buffer_size = 256K
read_rnd_buffer_size = 512K
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 8M
default-storage-engine=InnoDB
lower_case_table_names=1
server-id = 1


replicate-same-server-id = 0
auto-increment-increment = 2
auto-increment-offset = 1
log-bin = <>mysql-bin.log
log-bin-index = <>/mysql-bin.index
log-slave-updates
replicate-do-db=schema_replicate
binlog-do-db=schema_replicate
replicate-do-table=schema_replicate.ref_tbl
relay-log = <>/relay-bin
relay-log-index = <>/relay-bin.index
relay-log-info-file = <>/relay-bin.info
slave-skip-errors = 1062

# binary logging format - mixed recommended
#binlog_format=mixed
# required unique id between 1 and 2^32 - 1
# defaults to 1 if master-host is not set
# but will not function as a master if omitted
server-id       = 1

# The number of seconds the server waits for activity on a noninteractive
# connection before closing it. Range: 1-2147483.  2073600 is 24 days, close
# to maximum
wait_timeout=2073600

# Replication Slave (comment out master section to use this)
#
# To configure this host as a replication slave, you can choose between
# two methods :

innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:10M:autoextend

innodb_buffer_pool_size = 48M
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 2M

innodb_log_file_size = 16M
innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 50

[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet = 16M

[mysql]
no-auto-rehash
# Remove the next comment character if you are not familiar with SQL
#safe-updates

[myisamchk]
key_buffer_size = 20M
sort_buffer_size = 20M
read_buffer = 2M
write_buffer = 2M
[mysqlhotcopy]
interactive-timeout
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it we were using the default schema while running the DML statements, just specifying the SCHEMA1.TABLE_NAME isn't sufficient enough. 
We had to give 'use ' and then run the statements on .

Example, when you are logged into SCHEMA1

```
update SCHEMA2.<TABLE_NAME> set FIELD1='VALUE';
```

The above statement does not replicate the SCHEMA2., rather the below works

```
use SCHEMA2;
update SCHEMA2.<TABLE_NAME> set FIELD1='VALUE';
```

This might be a common issue, but I couldn't find any similar solutions, so posted this one.

Comment: You are probably using master-side replication filtering, which are a recipe for replication breaking (you just suffered from one of its many problems). Edit: Yes, you are, it is on your config file.

Answer (score 0):

Activate the [general log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_general_log) on both servers at runtime (beware of doing it when you have a lot of load, as that will make all your queries slower):

```
SET GLOBAL general_log = 1;
```

You will find it on `datadir`/`hostname`.log, or you can change its location with the `general_log_file` parameter.

There, all connections and queries sent to the server will be logged. Compare what NaviCat and Workbench are doing to identify a possible problem. You can also check the contents of the binary logs with the utility `mysqlbinlog` and the changes applied with the commands `SHOW MASTER STATUS` and `SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G` on each server, making sure that the replication is not broken (very common in master-master replications).

Remember to disable the general log after you are done:

```
SET GLOBAL general_log = 0;
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Turns out it we were using the default schema while running the update statements, just specifying the <SCHEMA.TABLE_NAME> isn't sufficient enough. We had to give 'use <SCHEMA>' and then run the statements on <SCHEMA.TABLE_NAME>.